# Angular (directive newbie): How to add date time-picker to ngModel so that it can be validated?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am very new to Angular and have a specific use case in mind
I have a form which has two fields - Name and datetime.

The name is ng-model but datetime is not since it is not part of Angular and is a jquery component

**What I want to do?**
Here is the plunker = http://plnkr.co/edit/wGrvXAFmPGoYSwh9GfxH?p=preview

a.) I want to associate date to ngModel like ngModel="transaction.date"
b.) validate it as **required** using Angular way

Something which will look like (much like Angular)

```
<input type="text" name="transactionDate" ng-model="transaction.date" data-date-format="yyyy-mm-dd hh:ii" required>
```

**Why?**
a.) To to things Angular way
b.) It makes model more consistent to test, validate

I asked this question on [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16442785/using-bootstrap-datetime-picker-with-angularjs/16448727?noredirect=1#16448727) and it was recommended to use custom directive, can someone give me direction with example how to do it?

Please guide me further since I am not able to validate it currently

Thank you very much

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Based on Ketan's answer, I had to write a new directive and associate the value form jQuery to ng-model, which then is validated with form. The directive looks like

```
app.directive('dateTime', function(){
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    require: '?ngModel',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs, ngModel){
      if (!ngModel) {
        console.log('no model, returning');
        return;
      }

      element.bind('blur keyup change', function() {
        console.log('datetime changed: ', $('.form_datetime input').val());
        scope.$apply(read);
      });

      read();

      function read() {
        ngModel.$setViewValue(element.val());
      }
    }
  }
});
```

The plunker can be found [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/wGrvXAFmPGoYSwh9GfxH?p=preview)

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you know how to write directives, you need to use the `NgModelController` inside your directive and use the `$setViewValue(value)` method. (See example the below page).

http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngModel.NgModelController

This has to be called from your custom Datepicker event which triggers when the user completes the selection.